# Performace of PHP page after URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have written a rewrite rule for my page

`http://localhost/project/new.php?action=login` like

`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) $1.php?action=$2`

Now my file is can be accessed at `http://localhost/project/new/login` which is the exactly the same thing i wanted, but the problem is that the page is loading too slowly despite of the fact that i am running the application on local server.As soon as i remove the .htaccess file it loads quickly...

Comment: Even with .htaccess rules in place if you visit `http://localhost/project/new.php?action=login` do you find it slow?

Comment: No it loads in a flash if i visit the URL mentioned by u ....

Comment: maybe its your local system, that is slow?

Comment: Ok, can you enable Rewrite log and post the matching logs in your question above.

Comment: Can you please tell me where are these logs saved ???

Comment: @KingCrunch: as i mentioned in my question that when i remove .htaccess file it loads very quickly .....

Comment: Please check your httpd.conf to know where logs files are located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified my rule a bit like `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+) new.php?action=login` the performance is a bit better now but  i think i will have to  add a separate rule  for every file that i want to add ....

Answer (score 2):

If you dont modify the PHP page, than is not the performance of the PHP page that you should worry, but the performance of the server or of the rewrite rule. The main "classical" way to do this is called **front controller** where you create a redirect rule to a unique point of entry from where you distribute the calls accordingly using a Router class in PHP. this is more maintainable and extendable.

[The front controller pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html) by Martin Fowler, a design pattern in more programming languages, PHP is quite new at this. [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.front.html) is implementing it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be that slow. Try to add your rewrite rules to httpd.conf as it the rules will not be parsed for every request.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.